# Jest.fn() called 0 times, should be called once. (checked other questions)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have checked some other questions on this topic but for the life of me cannot figure out what is causing this mock function to not be called. Below I provide all the code that I think is relevant but feel free to ask if I need to include any more.

We use React-Hook-Forms.

Before Each:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    await act(async () => {
      history = createMemoryHistory({
        initialEntries: ["/admin/615"]
      });
      container = renderWithRouter(
        <Admin
          setCollections={mockSetCollections}
          setCourses={mockSetCourses}
          data={mockData}
          isAdmin={true}
          azureOid={1}
        />,
        "/admin/:id",
        history,
        "/courses"
      );
    });
  });
```

Test:

```
test("Admin page calls mockSetCourses when submit button is clicked for Editing a Course", async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("adminSubmitButton"));
  });
  expect(mockSetCourses).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

On Submit:

```
const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data)
    let formData = getFormattedFormData(data);
    let collectionsDuplicates = getCollectionsDuplicates();

    let descriptionError =
      formData.description === "" || formData.description === "<p><br></p>";

    if (collectionsDuplicates.length > 0 && descriptionError) {
      setErrorMessage({ collection: true, description: true });
    } else if (collectionsDuplicates.length > 0 && !descriptionError) {
      setErrorMessage({ collection: true, description: false });
    } else if (!collectionsDuplicates.length > 0 && descriptionError) {
      setErrorMessage({ collection: false, description: true });
    } else {
      setErrorMessage({ collection: false, description: false });

      if (id) {
        editCourse(id, formData, setRedirect, setCourses, setCollections);
      } else {
        addCourse(formData, setRedirect, azureOid, setCourses, setCollections);
      }
    }
  };
```

I have checked that the correct button is being clicked and it is.

Edit:
The request that uses the function:

```
export const editCourse = (
  id,
  formData,
  setRedirect,
  setCourses,
  setCollections
) => {
  sendRequest(
    "patch",
    `courses/${id}`,
    () => {
      getCourses(setCourses);
      getCollections(setCollections);
      setRedirect(`/courses/${id}`);
    },
    formData
  );
};
```

Comment: `expect(mockSetCourses).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`because of this line

Comment: @RahulKumar this is what we are trying to assert though? Before we made some changes to the form this test was passing and ALL that has been changed is adding some configuration to the use form method (mode: all, revalidate mode: on Touched)

Comment: Just as a sanity check, what if you do add a `console.log('About to call setCourses!');` wherever you actually call the function? (There's no code that would call it here.)

Comment: add the code for `mockSetCourses` mock function

Comment: @AKX I have updated my question to include the code that uses this function when I add the log you have suggested it does not even log anywhere in console.

Comment: @lhuf I assume `sendRequest` will only call the inner callback when the request is successful. Have you mocked whatever underlies `sendRequest` accordingly too, so it will succeed in your test?